# Displayed video in Jupyter Notebook is unplayable

Tags: python, html, video, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to embed a video on my local drive in Jupyter Notebook.

The file name is "openaigym.video.6.7524.video000000.mp4" and it is in a folder "gym-results".

Using the following code produces nothing whatsoever:

```
from IPython.display import Video
Video("./gym-results/openaigym.video.4.7524.video000000.mp4",embed =True)
```

If I try to use HTML directly (which I got from [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-display-rich-output-media-audio-video-image-etc-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook/)), it produces an unplayable video:

```
from base64 import b64encode
def video(fname, mimetype):
    from IPython.display import HTML
    video_encoded = b64encode(open(fname, "rb").read())
    video_tag = '<video controls alt="test" src="data:video/{0};base64,{1}">'.format(mimetype, video_encoded)
    return HTML(data=video_tag)

path= f"./gym-results/openaigym.video.6.7524.video000000.mp4"
video(path, "mp4")
```

That is, it produces the following:

[image]

Which cannot be started.
**How do I solve this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method:** it worked with me!

[image]

**Second method:** You could try this as well:

```
from ipywidgets import Video
Video.from_file("./play_video_test.mp4", width=320, height=320)
```

[image]

**Third method:** you should change the type of the `cell` from code to `Markdown`

```
<video controls src="./play_video_test.mp4">animation</video>
```

If all solutions do not work with you, I recommend you to update your jupyter notebook by `conda update jupyter` or `pip install -U jupyter` and go through each solution one more again.

Comment: Maybe you have done some setup that I haven't ? (Or vice versa)

Comment: Did you run the code and it does not work with you?

Comment: What was the output of the cell also blocked screen or an error message?

Comment: "Did you run the code and it does not work with you?", yes I ran my own code already obviously, and I also tried yours based on ipywidgets. The latter one doesn't produce anything (not even a non-playable video). There are never any error messages. (There IS an error message when I fill in a non-existent dummy file name though, so it's not that it doesn't find the file).

Comment: Give it a try and rename your video file to 'test.mp4' because there are a lot of dots in the name of your file.

Comment: Try to use online jupyter notebook https://hub.gke2.mybinder.org/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-fw1tzqsy/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb   upload your video from file menu and then open.

Comment: One of the most causes of not running videos. It is not updated. Try to update jupyter notebook by 'conda update jupyter' or 'pip install -U jupyter '

Comment: I updated the answer, it may work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the third solution has the same effect, and after updating using your conda command, the same problem persists.

Comment: Did you try to use your code with online jupyter notebook?

Comment: Oh so sorry. I missed that. I will try it once I am at my pc again.

Comment: This link gives me "binder not found": "Oops!
We can't seem to find the Binder page you are looking for.
404 error"

Comment: This link will work with you: https://jupyter.org/try   but click the first option 'try classic notebook'

Comment: I don't think there is the option of uploading a video there. This is what the file menu looks like: https://i.gyazo.com/ddb1c9984b47b0c54d3f8d392a254031.png

Comment: Click open from the menu and select your video

Comment: Ok, I uploaded it and I get the same result. I suppose this means the problem is with my mp4 file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should use another.mp4 file and you can share with me your code.

Comment: Make sure you use mp4 file not other formats